# Android Realm + RxJava - Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, rx-java

I'm trying to implement RxJava + Realm + Retrofit + Repository Pattern

Here's my local implementation:

```
@Override
public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull final String query) {

        return Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Page.class)
                .equalTo("query", query)
                .findAll()
                .asObservable()
                .cast(Page.class);
    }
```

Here's my remote implementation:

```
 @Override
 public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull String query) {
        return mWikiServices.search(query).map(new Func1<Result, Page>() {
            @Override
            public Page call(Result result) {
                final List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>(result.getQuery().getPages().values());
                return pages.get(0);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's my repo implementation:

```
 final Observable<Page> localResult = mSearchLocalDataSource.search(query);
 final Observable<Page> remoteResult = mSearchRemoteDataSource.search(query)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Page page) {
                        //mSearchLocalDataSource.save(query, page);
                        //mResultCache.put(query, page);
                    }
                });

        return Observable.concat(localResult, remoteResult)
                .first()
                .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

And finally here's my subscription in presenter.

```
final Subscription subscription = mSearchRepository.search(this.mQuery)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        // Completed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        mView.onDefaultMessage(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Page page) {
                        mView.onDefaultMessage(page.getContent());
                    }
                });

        mCompositeSubscription.add(subscription);
```

When i run code i get this exception: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

I tried official solutions in Realm Github repo but none of them worked. Still get this exception.

I think i get this exception because i'm subscribing on an io thread. Realm instance gets created in Main thread. So i get this exception.

Are there any implementation offers?

Thanks.

Comment: so **where** exactly are you getting the error? line-wise

Comment: By the way let me cite [my article](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149): *if you see code like `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(…)`, it’s going to break sooner or later.*

Comment: @EpicPandaForce in concat.first().

Comment: I'm also citing my other article so you'll see the big picture of how Realm is designed to work as a zero-copy database  :  https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f#.s85b64kqw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research i found the solution.

First let's remember the problem: When i subscribe a Schedulars.io thread and try to get data from realm or retrofit i get "Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created"

Main problem in this case is i create Realm instance in Main thread but try to access it from worker thread.

We can subscribe realm on main thread but this's not a good practice. When i use

```
realm.where("query",query).findFirstAsync().asObservable();
```

as an example in Github repo i get stuck at

```
Observable.concat(localResult, remoteResult).first();
```

What's my solution?

In our Repository implementation still we have two observables for remote and local like below:

```
final Observable<Page> localResult = mSearchLocalDataSource.search(query);
final Observable<Page> remoteResult = mSearchRemoteDataSource.search(query)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Page page) {
                        if (page != null) {
                            mSearchLocalDataSource.save(query, page);
                            mResultCache.put(query, page);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Take attention on we save to data and cache in memory when we get data from remote.

Still we concat two observables if we cannot get data from cache.

```
return Observable.concat(localResult, remoteResult)
                .first()
                .map(new Func1<Page, Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public Page call(Page page) {
                        if (page == null) {
                            throw new NoSuchElementException("No result found!");
                        }
                        return page;
                    }
                });
```

With concat we try to get data from realm and if we can't we try to get from remote.

Here's remote observable implementation:

```
@Override
public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull String query) {
        return mWikiServices.search(query).flatMap(new Func1<Result, Observable<Page>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Page> call(Result result) {
                final ArrayList<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>(result.getQuery().getPages().values());
                Log.i("data from", "remote");
                return Observable.from(pages).first();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's local source implementation:

```
@Override
public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull final String query) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Page>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Page> subscriber) {
                final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfiguration);
                final Page page = realm.where(Page.class)
                        .equalTo("query", query)
                        .findFirst();
                if (page != null && page.isLoaded() && page.isValid()) {
                    Log.i("data from", "realm");
                    subscriber.onNext(realm.copyFromRealm(page));
                } else {
                    Observable.empty();
                }
                subscriber.onCompleted();
                realm.close();
            }
        });
    }
```

The point is i create a new Observable and get data from realm in there. So we create realm instance and use it in same thread. (io thread). We create copy of object to get rid of illegal state exception.

When we get data from realm if null we return an empty observable to do not get stuck in concat operation.

if we get page, it's valid and loaded we send to subscriber and complete operation.

Here how we can save the data we get from remote to realm:

```
@Override
public void save(@NonNull String query, @NonNull Page page) {
        final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfiguration);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        final Page p = realm.createObject(Page.class);
        p.setQuery(query);
        p.setId(page.getId());
        p.setTitle(page.getTitle());
        p.setContent(page.getContent());
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(p);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }
```

Here's example source code.
https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight

Good luck.

Comment: In the end, you went with Viraj Tank's [safe integration](https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/realm-integration-in-android-best-practices-449919d25f2f#.9cvj3gvta) solution, while what I was supporting is the [deep integration](https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/deep-integration-of-realm-in-android-production-code-part-2-with-mvp-4cf44ab6289d#.xkihifr9p) solution. Both of them work.

Comment: Oh sure. :) i'm sorry i do not have enough time to read what you send. thanks for your help. i'll accept your answer.

Comment: You should select your own answer. I do accept an upvote though :)

Answer (score 1):

**LAST EDIT:** technically, both solutions work, it's a question of as Viraj Tank said - ["safe integration"](https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/realm-integration-in-android-best-practices-449919d25f2f#.soh4dfrr1) vs ["deep integration"](https://medium.com/@Viraj.Tank/realm-integration-in-android-best-practices-449919d25f2f#.soh4dfrr1).

Still, the proper deep integration method would be to have separate download from the service, and a subscriber that listens to changes in the underlying Realm. (`realmResults.asObservable().subscribe()`).

---

---

I honestly can't help but feel like this is conceptually flawed.

First thing first, the Realm query is executed on the main thread at creation

```
@Override
public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull final String query) {

        return Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Page.class)
```

Creating an instance of Realm that will never be closed.

Additionally, it uses `asObservable()` in conjunction with `first()`, which makes me wonder why you add change listeners to your results in the first place through `asObservable()` rather than just calling `Observable.just(results)`.

Then, it seems like the remote data source obtains and adds the element to Realm and shows the downloaded item immediately, rather than the elements be supplied directly managed by Realm via change listener and thus providing auto-updates. In which case I'm not really sure what Realm is doing.

Anyways, my initial guess would be that you *might* be able to make your code work with the following lines

```
final Observable<Page> localResult = mSearchLocalDataSource.search(query)
                                                           .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
final Observable<Page> remoteResult = mSearchRemoteDataSource.search(query)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Page>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Page page) {
                    //mSearchLocalDataSource.save(query, page);
                    //mResultCache.put(query, page);
                }
            });
```

Considering you don't seem to be relying on Realm's auto-updating feature, you could consider using `realm.copyFromRealm(obj)` to create an unmanaged copy which can be passed between threads.

---

But in reality, for proper Realm usage, you should have two subscriptions - a single data flow from the network to the Realm; and a subscription for `RealmResults<Page>.asObservable()` which would notify you when the pages are written to underneath by the network observable - [check out Christian Melchior's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38069544/2413303) for the idea.

[Personally, I skipped the Realm observable because the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` handled it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358679/2413303). So if you're showing multiple elements in a RecyclerView, then the Realm observable is not even needed, because the `RealmRecylerViewAdapter` manages its auto-updating through `RealmChangeListener` without relying on `asObservable()` to do it.

---

---

**EDIT:**

After forking [the asker's repository](https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight) as https://github.com/Zhuinden/wikilight , apparently I was right all along. The simple zero-copy solution would have been to add `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` for the local observable.

So surprisingly enough, not much changed.

```
    final Observable<Page> localResult = mSearchLocalDataSource.search(query).filter(new Func1<Page, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Page page) {
            return page != null;
        }
    }).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    final Observable<Page> remoteResult = mSearchRemoteDataSource.search(query).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Page>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Page page) {
                    if (page != null) {
                        mSearchLocalDataSource.save(query, page);
                      //  mResultCache.put(query, page);
                    }
                }
            });


    return Observable.concat(localResult, remoteResult)
            .first()
            .map(new Func1<Page, Page>() {
                @Override
                public Page call(Page page) {
                    if (page == null) {
                        throw new NoSuchElementException("No result found!");
                    }
                    return page;
                }
            });
```

But to be fair, the original solution seems to cut auto-updating out of the picture, so no `RealmChangeListener`s are used in the solution, and neither is `RealmObject.asObservable()`, so `copyFromRealm()` does make more sense. To make auto-updating work, this

```
@Override
public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull final String query) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Page>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Page> subscriber) {
            Realm realm = null;
            try {
                realm = mRealmManager.getRealm();

                final Page page = realm.where(Page.class).equalTo("query", query).findFirst();
                if(page != null && page.isLoaded() && page.isValid()) {
                    Log.i("data from", "realm");
                    subscriber.onNext(page);
                } else {
                    Log.i("data is", "empty");
                    Observable.empty();
                }
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } finally {
                if(realm != null) {
                    mRealmManager.closeRealm(realm);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Should be replaced with this:

```
@Override
public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull final String query) {
    Realm realm = mRealmManager.getRealm(); // UI thread only!
    final Page page = realm.where(Page.class).equalTo("query", query).findFirst();
    if(page != null) {
        Log.i("data from", "realm");
        return page.asObservable();
    } else {
        Log.i("data is", "empty");
        return Observable.empty();
    }
}
```

In the end, some additional architecturing could make this even better, but I think I'll just go sleep.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if it's a good practice to observe a db operation on main thread for non blocking ui.

Comment: If you use findAllAsync with a Realm on the UI thread, then the actual query is executed on a background thread... You just need to use change listener to know when it's loaded (or asObservable with filter, of course)

Comment: When i try to do that still get same exception. The main problem is when i get realm instance i'm on main thread and when i subscribe on observable i'm trying to access realm from a schedular.io thread. so i get this exception.

Comment: So subscribing the local observable on the main thread still didn't work? Maybe just also add the subscription 's subscribeOn to use the main thread too. I always get confused by subscribeOn but it might work.

Comment: I'll try but i assume it'll work because i create realm object in main thread and if i subscribe on main thread for local result i'll be using realm instance in same thread so i won't get this error. but the point is it's not a good practice to get data from db on main thread. so i don't want to use this solution.

Comment: How do you intend to show your RealmObject on the UI thread if the thread-confined RealmObject belongs to NOT the UI thread?  It HAS to belong to the UI thread, otherwise it'll fail with illegal thread access. Managed RealmObjects cannot be passed between threads.

Comment: You could probably also use `findFirstAsync().asObservable().filter(RealmObject::isValid).filter(RealmObject::isLoaded)`, still subscribing on the UI thread.

Comment: You can also use `realm.copyFromRealm(obj)` but I always say it's odd practice to copy out data from a zero-copy database; and with that you lose autoupdating and need to manage state persistence manually and all that

Comment: thanks for your help but your examples does not work for me.

Comment: which one? (i linked multiple), and how does it "not work"?

Comment: sorry i could not answer you quickly. blow i added my solution. if you want we can discuss it. i'll be glad to hear your opinions. thanks.

Comment: Well there are two ways to use Realm... One is to copy your objects from it and then pass it between threads but lose automatic persistence, the object being a single source of truth to the underlying database, and auto-updates. The other is to use managed realm objects, zero-copy, and auto-updates with listener for change. It's up to the user to determine which is "better", but I still feel iffy about copying data from a zero-copy database.