# RxJava with Realm

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm a new pioneer with a library Realm and RxJava and I have a question:
How Can I set up my new database and to set auto update on it? Instead of my main code, the Realm team suggests using Disposable, I tried to do it, but I got an exception: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'getList' not found in class 'Board'.` But I have this field

```
@SerializedName("list")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<List> list = new RealmList<>();

public RealmList<List> getList() {
    return list;
}
```

Attempt:

```
disposable = realm.where(Board.class).isNotNull("getList").findAllAsync().asFlowable()
                .filter(boards -> board.isLoaded())
                .flatMap(boards -> service.getFlowableBoard(currentBoard))
                .doOnNext(list -> {
                    if (list != null) {
                        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(list);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                        realm.close();
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(boards -> {
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new BoardAdapter(MainActivity.this, board.getList(), board.getBoard()));
                });
    } else {
        realm.copyToRealm((realm.where(Board.class).findAll()));
    }
```

My base hardcode is here:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String currentBoard = intent.getStringExtra(GET_B);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    OrderedRealmCollection<List> rr = null;
    Board board = new Board();

    BoardAdapter adapter = new BoardAdapter(this, rr, board.getBoard());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Log.e("MY_LOGS", currentBoard);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    //We need to use Realm.init, because without it, we will catching exception
    Realm.init(MainActivity.this);
    //We need to use,without - we will get Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmQuery io.realm.Realm.where(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    Service service = retrofit.create(service.class);

    Observable<Board> observable = Observable.create(e -> realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Board.class).findAll()));

    if (isNetworkAvialable()) {
        service.getRxBoard(currentBoard)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .doOnNext(database -> {
                    if (database != null) {
                        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        //problem
                        realm.executeTransaction(trRealm -> {
                            trRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(database);
                        });
                    } else {
                        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(database);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                        realm.close();
                    }
                })
                .mergeWith(observable)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(board1 -> {
                //The second parameter - RealmList
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new BoardAdapter(MainActivity.this, board.getList(), board.getBoard()));
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
    } else {
        realm.copyToRealm((realm.where(Board.class).findAll()));
    }
}
```

And after this I have an exception: `Only use this adapter with managed RealmCollection, for un-managed lists you can just use the BaseRecyclerViewAdapter`

My Adapter is here:

```
public class BoardAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<List, BoardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static String TAG = "MY LOGS";
String board;
private Context context;

public BoardAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<List> list, String board) {
    super(list, true);//Problem is here
    this.context = context;
    this.board = board;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView subject;
    TextView comment;
    TextView views;
    ImageView image;
    CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        subject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
        comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        views = itemView.findViewById(R.id.views);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.opPost);
    }
}


@Override
public BoardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.board_activity, parent, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: " + view + viewType);
    return new BoardAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

private List<Board> boards;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BoardAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final List list = getData().get(position);//The getData() was previously missing
    holder.subject.setText(Html.fromHtml(list.getSubject()));
    holder.comment.setText(Html.fromHtml(list.getComment()));
    holder.views.setText(Html.fromHtml(list.getDate()));
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    int files = list.getFiles().size();
    if (files > 0) {
        for (File file : list.getFiles()) {
            if (file.getPath() != null) {
                holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String f = file.getPath();
                Picasso.with(context).load(BASE_URL + f).into(holder.image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if it is possible how to simplify the code in the MainActivity?

Comment: The field is called `list`, not `getList`.

Comment: `realm.copyToRealm((realm.where(Board.class).findAll()));` this doesn't really seem to do anything useful. Why have it?

Comment: I think if this code works then you should end up in some infinite loop from triggering realm change event and from writing as a side effect.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I am correcting my mistakes. After replacing the field, I have an exception - Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created. I think I will follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357345/android-realm-rxjava-realm-access-from-incorrect-thread-realm-objects-can-o#39358559